# AUCTeX LaTeX-insert-item not environment-specific for tabular

Tags: emacs, auctex

When Emacs is in AUCTeX's LaTeX mode, the command `LaTeX-insert-item` (`C-c C-j` or `M-<Ret>`) starts with a new `\item` in an `itemize` (or similar) environment. According to the AUCTeX manual, the command should be aware of the `tabular` environment and yield a new line in the table (with the `&`s and `\\`). This is not working for me (Emacs 24.3.1, AUCTeX 11.87). Any idea?

Comment: Which manual are you reading? You're using an outdated version of AUCTeX, this feature has been introduced later. You have to update the package, use Emacs's package manager

Comment: Used Emacs's package manager, resulting in latex-mode not working anymore. Probably there is a conflict with the previous installed auctex.

Comment: Re-installed Emacs (apt-get) and AUCTeX (Emacs package manager), everything seems fine now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a system update solve the problem